# Too many unique state objects?

Tags: c#, directx, monogame

So I've experienced a DirectX issue, and an exception is thrown as describes:

```
D3D11_ERROR_TOO_MANY_UNIQUE_STATE_OBJECTS
0x887C0001

The application has exceeded the maximum number of unique state objects per Direct3D device. 
The limit is 4096 for feature levels up to 11.1
```

And cannot find documentation on this issue. For reference there are only 3 models being draw to screen using Monogame's BasicEffect, each model has less than 50 polygons.

How is this occurring, and how can it be resolved?

Comment: I suspect that you are recreating them on each draw call and then not disposing of them properly.

Comment: You see, that is what I originally thought... And using the monogame framework I thought maybe it would already be managed. But it appears not so, a fix that I found but costly was to use vertex buffers and index buffers manually, in a nested loop fixed on rendering and disposing but I still received the error. I received it like 30 seconds after the first render call, for 50 polygons @ 60 fps? I'm questioning the integrity of the rendering around the mesh. Is there anyway I can resolve this more effectively?

Answer (score 0):

This was the fix that I found most effective:

```
static void Render(GraphicsDevice gd, ModelMesh mesh) {
    gd.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullNone;

    for (int i = 0; i < mesh.MeshParts.Count; i++) {
        int vertexCount = mesh.MeshParts[i].NumVertices;
        VertexBuffer vb = mesh.MeshParts[i].VertexBuffer;
        IndexBuffer ib = mesh.MeshParts[i].IndexBuffer;

        gd.SetVertexBuffer(vb);
        gd.Indices = ib;

        EffectPass pass = mesh.MeshParts[i].Effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0];
        pass.Apply();
        int startIndex = mesh.MeshParts[i].StartIndex;
        int primitiveCount = mesh.MeshParts[i].PrimitiveCount;

        gd.DrawInstancedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, startIndex, primitiveCount, 0);
    }
```